# Create selector drawable dynamically for enable and disable state

Tags: android, statelistdrawable

I want to create selector dynamically for button. When button is disabled(`setEnable(false)`), its color should change.

Comment: read about `StateListDrawable`

Comment: i have read but its not working for state_enable="false" state.

Comment: it is working, many selectors use that state

Comment: its my bad i was having a very silly mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out having silly mistake in my code.

Method to create selector

```
 public static StateListDrawable createSelectorsWithStates(int[] state,
        Drawable[] drawables)
    {
    StateListDrawable stateDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
    for (int i = 0; i < state.length; i++)
    {   
        stateDrawable.addState(new int[] { state[i] }, drawables[i]);
    }
    return stateDrawable;
    }
```

To set drawable to a button:

```
Drawable enable = ResourceManager.createRectangleShape(
             bgColor, null, borderRadius);
        enable.setAlpha((int)0.5f);
        Drawable disable = ResourceManager.createRectangleShape(
            bgColor, null, borderRadius);
        disable.setAlpha(150);

        ResourceManager.setDrawable(v1, ResourceManager
            .createSelectorsWithStates(new int[] {
                android.R.attr.state_enabled,
                -android.R.attr.state_enabled },
                new Drawable[] { enable, disable }));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) is the answer.

If you just want **change the color** based on different status, however, don' t want write a bunch of selector related xml.

The key point is **dynamically** build a StateListDrawable.

I' m tired of writing xml, so I create a [StateListDrawableBuilder](https://gist.github.com/longkai/b4474389fc2b7c2f0151) and a [DrawableBuilder](https://gist.github.com/longkai/607247b52aa29546effc) to do so.

Have a look at it, sorry for not showing any code.

Answer (score -4):

```
btn.setEnable(false);
btn.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

please do not use selector.